# Two users accepting ownership of a single case at the same time

Tags: case, servicecloud, ownership, queue

We recently implemented an open sharing model for cases, in which their is a sharing rule to allow all internal users read/write access. Additionally, users with a "Support" profile have "Transfer Cases" enabled, which gives them the ability to change the ownership of any case.

This has created a challenge with queue management, wherein two users could be viewing the same case at the same time, and each one accepts ownership of the case. When this happens, the user that accept ownership last is unaware that another user has already taken ownership.

Is there any thing that can be done to prevent this from happening? Ideally, the second user wouldn't be able to take ownership without being warned that the case had been edited since it was last loaded in their browser.

Comment: One solution, which is probably too heavy, would be to implement some vf which leverages salesforces streaming API. This would require you to setup a query which searches for the change then updates the vf page to notify the user. It seems very heavy for a simple function, but would probably work for you.

Comment: Queue managed cases are typically better with a "Get Next Case" button (IMO) which can have apex logic to assign a next case. Within the "assignment" of the case, you actually lock the case during processing so another user can't get that case. This prevents two users from "getting" the same case. There's really no system way to do it unless you had like an auto refresh list view in the console or something of the sort.

Comment: With the Salesforce Console it's trivial to use Push Notifications.

Outside of the console you may be able to use Push Topics and the streaming API to listen for these changes and trigger a page refresh. 

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_push_notifications.htm